# Clean URLs don't work after install in Backdrop

Tags: backdrop

I'm intalling civicrm on backdrop cms. Setup returns that installation was succesful.
I see the link in the admin bar, but when clicked, the link gives me 404 error.

If I add "?q=", links works, the page display, but any other link doesn't work.

Clean urls works fine on the site.

I'm performing a migration from Drupal 7, were civicrm was updated and functioning.

System:
Backdrop 1.18.0
MySQL Database MySQL, MariaDB, or equivalent version 5.5.5-10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
php Version: 7.3.19-1~deb10u1 (PHP information)
Servidor web Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Civicrm 5.33.1

I would appreciate any advice.

Andrés

Comment: Do clean URLs work elsewhere on the Backdrop site?

Comment: Yes. Civicrm URLs work when I add '?q=' manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

searching in the apache2 error.log I saw:

[Tue Jan 26 14:15:46.726049 2021] [negotiation:error] [pid 16679] [client 127.0.0.1:44192] AH00687: Negotiation: discovered file(s) matching request: /home/(...)backdrop/civicrm (None could be negotiated)., referer: http://(...)backdrop/?q=civicrm&reset=1

Then I searched the web and found this [post](https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/foros/Apache/1422809-solucionado-Negotiation-discovered-files-matching-request.html) that explains that in the line

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

of my virtual host configuration (file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/backdrop.conf) I should delete the word "MultiViews".

I restarted apache and civicrm links started working when I enabled Clean URLs.

Thanks,

Andrés

Answer (score 2):

If Clean URLs are working in Backdrop, but not in Civi under Backdrop, then the problem is almost certainly in `civicrm.settings.php`.  My Backdrop/Civi sites (and also Drupal 7/Civi sites) have this snippet of code in `civicrm.settings.php`:

```
if (!defined('CIVICRM_CLEANURL')) {
  if ( function_exists('variable_get') && variable_get('clean_url', '0') != '0') {
    define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 1 );
  }
  else {
    define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 0);
  }
}
```

I suspect you're either missing this code, or perhaps there's something wrong with your "clean_url" variable in Backdrop.

Try replacing that with just this and let us know if it solves the problem?

```
define('CIVICRM_CLEANURL', 1 );
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. I have this code on civicrm.settings.php, but changing for the last line,even so does not solve the problem.  I think I could have something wrong with the definition in the database in backdrop.

Comment: FYI this snippet has been updated to work better with Backdrop (using config management rather than variables): https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/48538a6f103ea739a54f01e8651aa34f33cba8fa